# What all happens underneath the command Service Update?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

When we run the following command, which of the following events does not occur?

$ docker service update --replicas=5 --detach=true nginx1

a) The state of the service is updated to 5 replicas, which is stored in the swarm's internal storage. --I believe this is True

b) Docker Swarm recognizes that the number of replicas that is scheduled now does not match the declared state of 5.  --Not sure, ultimately it will check but how it happens on the timeline: immediately?/periodically?

c) This command checks aggregated logs on the updated replicas.  --Don't think this is true but not sure.

d) Docker Swarm schedules 5 more tasks (containers) in an attempt to meet the declared state for the service. ----I believe this is True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D) Docker Swarm recognizes that the number of replicas that is scheduled now does not match the declared state of 5.